# Ember Data sending OPTIONS requests after save

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

After sucessfully updating an ember-data model, ember-data sends an OPTIONS request.

First of all, I would like to know why it sends an OPTIONS request.

And the actual problem is, that this options request is sent to the "location" where the put request returned from. Which is problematic because, I am using grunt-proxy and forward my requests to another domain. But the response from my PUT of course has this "other" domain as location. And the OPTIONS request ist then sent directly to this domain, which is of course not working due to CORS requests.

Additional Comment:
I found out that my PUT request returns a 302 Temporarily moved. I have to be honest, I have no idea, why because when I request my put Endpoint directly with some data, I never get a 302, always 204. 
Could this be the reason why ember-data making the OPTIONS request?

Comment: What protocols your client using? I was faced OPTIONS problem in case of switching protocol (http->htpps) during request.

Comment: In my experience ember does not do this.  Rather it's an issue with the rails server and in my case it was how I configured cors.

Comment: I am using Symfony2 and I don't have CORS enabled. The problem is in my functional tests I get 204 and they all succeed only if ember makes the request it's an 302. I don't know why

Comment: @TrevTheDev Can you elaborate? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: When the request is sent to rails rack middleware determines if the request is from a valid endpoint (usually a page that rails has served up) and either allows it or disallows it.  If your ember app is not served up from the same server by default it is disallowed.  To allow it one has to install the 'rack-cors' gem and configure it to allow remote destinations e.g.  
config.middleware.insert_before Warden::Manager, Rack::Cors do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource %r{/api*},
                 headers: :any,
                 methods: [:get, :post, :put]
       end
   end